# Как обновить Skype на Linux для 32bit?

Tags: linux, debian, skype

На Debian 8 32 bit пользовался Skype:

```
skype -v
Skype 4.3.0.37
© 2014 Skype and/or Microsoft
```

Недавно пришло письмо, мол с июля прекратим поддержку версий до 4.3 включительно, поэтому обновите версию. Иду на сайт https://www.skype.com/ru/download-skype/skype-for-linux/ вижу ссылку на deb пакет 64 bit версии, что не мой вариант. Поиск других версий на сайте всё равно приводит на эту страницу.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то обновить Skype для 32 bit версии?

Comment: Скорее всего - никак. Если бы хотя бы протокол открыли, то наверное были бы открытые реализации, а так - безысходность.

Comment: @donRumata, отчего же «безысходность»? наоборот, это очень положительно — ещё некоторое количество людей осознает, что проприетарщина — это раковая опухоль нашей цивилизации. а чем больше людей это осознает, тем скорее можно будет начать операцию по удалению опухоли.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ну жабер к сожалению не выстрелил, а вот всякие вайберы\вацапы цветут пышным цветом. Что меня крайне расстраивает.

Comment: @donRumata, так я ж не зря употребил слова «раковая опухоль». // чтобы было понятно, к чему я веду: вообразите себя начальником it-отдела всей планеты. станете ли вы растрачивать средства отдела на написание, например, сотен мессенджеров, или сосредоточите отдел на разработке  одного? в нерабочее время, бесплатно — конечно, пусть пишут что хотят  (вместо мессенджера подставьте любую другую функцию: редактор, антивирус и т.д. и т.п.)

Comment: edem, если процессор 64-битный, то можно добавить amd64 как foreign-architecture, установить пакет и загрузиться с 64-битным linux-ом. см. https://wiki.debian.org/CrossGrading с начала и до шага «install a kernel ...» включительно.

Comment: Используйте web версию скайпа и не заморачивайтесь с обновлениями

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я бы понаразрабатывал и понаутверждал бы кучу промышленных стандартов. Ну или принял бы те, которые в бою себя показали лучше всех. И открытые подробные спеки на всё. "Ах, если бы сбылась моя мечта" (с)

Comment: @donRumata, увы, не поможет: несть числа примерам, когда проприетарщики «забивали» на уже существующие стандарты. это ведь банально выгодно в конкурентной борьбе. даже термин для этого есть: [vendor lock-in](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не, ну при том, что я был бы начальником всего it на планете - хрен бы у меня кто разгулялся в плане "мы вам не покажем что под капотом, но мамой клянёмся - оно безопасно и работает".

Comment: Мне удалось скачать и установить http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
Источник: https://wiki.debian.org/ru/skype

Answer (score 7, accepted):

если процессор поддерживает «[длинные инструкции](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode)» (т.е., по-простому, «64-битный»), то можно добавить архитектуру `amd64` как дополнительную (*foreign arch*), установить и запустить 64-битную сборку программы *linux* (т.е., перезагрузить компьютер), после чего можно будет устанавливать и, главное, запускать программы, собранные для 64-битной архитектуры процессора.

1. узнать, поддерживает ли процессор «шестидесятичетырёхбитность»:

   ```
   $ grep -o -w 'lm' /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u
   ```

   если команда вернула строку `lm`, значит — поддерживает. если нет, дальше можно не читать.
2. посмотреть, какая архитектура является «родной» с точки зрения программы *dpkg*:

   ```
   $ dpkg --print-architecture
   ```
3. добавить дополнительную архитектуру:

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
   ```
4. посмотреть, какие архитектуры дополнительно подключены (с т.з. *dpkg*):

   ```
   $ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
   ```
5. обновить списки пакетов и установить 64-битную сборку программы *linux*:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get install linux-image-amd64:amd64
   ```
6. перезагрузившись и выбрав нужный пункт в меню загрузчика, убедиться, что выполняется именно эта версия программы:

   ```
   $ uname -r
   3.16.0-4-amd64
   ```
7. всё, можно устанавливать и запускать 64-битные блобы!

Comment: После перезагрузки `uname -r` выдаёт `3.16.0-4-686-pae` как и было. Какой шаг пропущен, чтобы "подтянулась" 64-я версия?

Comment: @edem, linux нужной версии установился? значит, просто по умолчанию загружается старая версия. выберите вручную или, если нет возможности, поманипулируйте переменной `GRUB_DEFAULT` в `/etc/default/grub` (надо запускать `sudo update-grub`, чтобы эти изменения были перенесены в `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`)

Comment: Да, запустил, установил Skype, но он не запустился, правда это уже другая проблема.

Comment: @edem, раз новый linux загрузился, версию `686-pae` можно удалять. тогда и манипуляций с конфигурацией загрузчика не потребуется.

Answer (score 0):

На работе используем веб версию Skype on Linux. Решает все головные боли.

https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-5-0-for-Linux-Beta-is-here/td-p/4609846